# Different URL paths in different tabs depending on id

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Let's say a user has a list of projects, and each `project` has it's own set of various collection items of `charts`, `reports`, `tags`, etc associated by `project._id`

When a user selects a `project`, all the associated collection items are viewable by route, for example `/project/<projectId>/chart/<chartId>`

Currently, a user can only view one project at a time. If he opens up a new tab or a new browser, he can still only view the one project. If he switches the project, all the other tabs/windows reactively change to the new project. This is because currently the project is tied to `Meteor.user.profile.projectId` (but I am looking for a better way).

I would like to change this behaviour so that tabs and windows are independent of each other. If a user pastes `project\project1` into a new window it should load that and it's associated collections even if his current tab is in `project\project2`. I hope that makes sense.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I am looking for suggestions and solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this can easily be accomplished using session variables:

1. set a default somewhere in your client code, `Session.setDefault('project', 1)` (or make sure that project being undefined is handled gracefully)
2. when a user selects a project, set the variable:
   `Session.set('project', [selectedProjectId])`
3. Wherever you need to decide which project to show: `Session.get('project')`

Comment: I thought about this, but I am not sure if this will work because Sessions don't persist across page loads. So let's say a user clicks on a link (say from an email) blah.com/project/project2/chart/chartid. How does meteor set session project on the client side? Would love an example if you don't mind.

Comment: actually, let me give this a try. i think i get what you're saying. I am already using a session variable to manage which project is currently chosen. I think I just have to remove the user.profile.projectId bit and it should work. Each tab will have its own Session var rather than a common one defined under user.profile

Comment: yup, that was it. thanks! i was definitely overthinking this one.